# Migrating to ES6 classes in React, dealing with Mixins that interact with state

Tags: reactjs, inheritance, ecmascript-6, mixins

We are preparing to migrate our React codebase to use ES6 classes, and of course that means dealing with all of our mixins that we have. I've explored the documentation that discusses ways of converting mixins such as using Higher order components or taking utility methods and putting them in imported modules. However, we have some mixins for which these methods will not work.

One simple example is a mixin that contains a version of the handleChange function from this forms doc: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html

It's a kind of utility function but since it interacts with state, it can't be placed in a separate module. It won't work as an HOC because then the nested component won't have access to the function.

It seems a good case for using inheritance but I keep reading about how that is discouraged and how it is unnecessary in React. I've also seen "mixin" patterns for ES6 that involve functions that return a subclass that adds functionality to another class, effectively dynamically subclassing something, but something about that doesn't seem right and it seems to miss the point about why mixins have fallen out of favor.

I suppose the code from the mixin can just be inlined into the components that use it but I hate having boilerplate code like that replicated everywhere. Plus, we have other mixins with the same concerns that contain more complex functionality which makes that even more problematic.

I'd love to hear people's suggestions for how best to handle this issue within best practice guidelines of react and ES6. Thanks!

Comment: Have the same issue right now, composition just isn't the perfect fit. Mixins were very useful in many circumstances since state could be interacted with.